# Trying to use dplyr in R to calculate values over time

Tags: r, dplyr, time

I am using a `data.frame` in `R`which has among column `car`, `car_speed_hist_0to70plus` (itself a vector), `date_corr`.

My time resolution is hour, on the time is `POSIXct` time.

I would like to calculate `sum(car * car_speed_hist_0to70plus[1]) / sum(car)` by day.

I have tried

```
library(dplyr)
library(timetk)
    
results %>%
      group_by(date_corr) %>%
      timetk::mutate_by_time(., .date_var = date_corr, .by = "day") %>%
      *** some function to average by group ***
```

but I think I am already doing everything wrong here.

Would you be able to help me?

### Edits

- `dput(head(results))` leads to:

```
    structure(list(instance_id = c(-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), 
        segment_id = c(9000004903, 9000004903, 9000004903, 9000004903, 
        9000004903, 9000004903), date = c("2023-03-29T19:00:00.000Z", 
        "2023-03-29T20:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-29T21:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-29T22:00:00.000Z", 
        "2023-03-29T23:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-30T00:00:00.000Z"), 
        interval = c("hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", "hourly", 
        "hourly"), uptime = c(0.4997222222, 0.6575, 0.9997222222, 
        0.9997222222, 0.9997222222, 0.9991666667), heavy = c(6, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), car = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bike = c(0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0), pedestrian = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), heavy_lft = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), heavy_rgt = c(6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), car_lft = c(2, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), car_rgt = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bike_lft = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bike_rgt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pedestrian_lft = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pedestrian_rgt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), direction = c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), car_speed_hist_0to70plus = list(c(50, 
        50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), car_speed_hist_0to120plus = list(
            c(50, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), timezone = c("Europe/Paris", 
        "Europe/Paris", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/Paris", 
        "Europe/Paris"), v85 = c(11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), date_corr = structure(c(1680116400, 
        1680120000, 1680123600, 1680127200, 1680130800, 1680134400
        ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Paris"), 
        valid = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame")
```

- In fact, my column is not exactly `share` but I am using values within `car_speed_hist_0to70plus`

Comment: Please include the error message and a sample from your dataset in some reproducible form, i.e. not as a screenshot but text output from `dput(head(results))`

Comment: Hi @margusl, I have added extra information to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want your grouping variable to be identical across the group, as each row has unique `date_corr` value (1h resolution), `group_by(date_corr)` would generate single-row groups. We'll get daily groups by transforming that `date_corr` to date first.

Extracting first elements of `car_speed_hist_0to70plus` vectors as a separate step makes it bit easier to follow:

```r
library(dplyr)
results %>% 
  # extact first items from car_speed_hist_0to70plus vectors
  mutate(spd0to70plus_1 = purrr::map_int(car_speed_hist_0to70plus, first)) %>% 
  group_by(date = lubridate::date(date_corr)) %>% 
  summarise(daily_avg = sum(car * spd0to70plus_1) / sum(car))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   date       daily_avg
#>   <date>         <dbl>
#> 1 2023-03-29        50
#> 2 2023-03-30       NaN
```

`map_int` is used here to access `car_speed_hist_0to70plus` items of each individual row, `first` is a function that gets called for each
`car_speed_hist_0to70plus` vector and it extracts first item from each of those vectors. Using `car_speed_hist_0to70plus[1]` in mutate would mean first item of `car_speed_hist_0to70plus` column, in this example it's a vector `c(50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

Another method would be rowwise grouping, then we could just use e.g. `car_speed_hist_0to70plus[1]` and `car_speed_hist_0to70plus[4]` in `mutate()`:

```
results %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(spd0to70plus_s = car_speed_hist_0to70plus[1] + car_speed_hist_0to70plus[4]) %>% 
  # or:
  # mutate(spd0to70plus_s = sum(car_speed_hist_0to70plus[c(1,4)]))
  group_by(date = lubridate::date(date_corr)) %>% 
  summarise(daily_avg = sum(car * spd0to70plus_s) / sum(car))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I had to use `map_dbl`instead of `map_int` as all values are not integers. However, I do not understand well this step. What if for instance, I wanted to sum  `car_speed_hist_0to70plus_1` to `car_speed_hist_0to70plus_4` as `spd0to70plus_s` and calculate at the end `summarise(daily_avg = sum(car * spd0to70plus_s) / sum(car))`

Comment: `mutate(results, s = car_speed_hist_0to70plus[1])` wouldn't be the first vector item from each row but it would be the first item of that whole column, so in this example all s values would hold `c(50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).` To access each vector from each row we can use map. Another option would be rowwise grouping, to get a sum of 2 values from those vectors I'd rather use that and maybe it would have been more intuitive with just one element too: `results %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(spd0to70plus_s = car_speed_hist_0to70plus[1] + car_speed_hist_0to70plus[4])` .

Comment: Many thanks! A last question: how could I group by week instead of day?

Comment: Got it! `group_by(date = lubridate::week(date_corr))`

Comment: @leparc , if your dates span across multiple years, you might want to be careful with `week()` , consider `week(c("2022-01-01", "2023-01-01"))`. A more general approach for basically any period is `lubridate::floor_date()`, i.e. `floor_date(date_corr, "week", week_start = 1)` (lubridate default weeks start is Sundays) - https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/round_date.html#ref-examples